# Why is the current angle negative?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, impedance-matching, power-factor-correction

[image]

I don't understand why the current angle is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a load that is described as "lagging" (or it has a lagging power factor), it (the load) has an equivalent series impedance that is a combination of inductive reactance and resistance. Under these circumstances the current's phase angle is negative with respect the the applied voltage phase angle (normally considered to be at 0°).

The presence of a transformer might slightly increase the angle but, it will still remain negative with respect the the voltage (the reference).